# How do I enforce a schema with an element that has a specific attribue value?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

My XML document looks like:

```
<Entries>
  <entry key="some string" value="some string"/>
  " "
  " "
  " "
</Entreis>
```

I need to enforce a rule that one of the entry elements must have a key of value "Version". What would the schema look like?

I tried

```
<xs:element name ="Entries">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:element name="entry">
        <xs:attribute name="key" fixed="Version" type="xs:string/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string/>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="entry">
        <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string/>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

but I get a validation error saying that I cannot have sequence appear twice in a complex type or that it is invalid or misplaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it cannot be done in xsd 1.0. You cannot have two elements with the same name but different (although similiar) structure at one place.

On the other side - what should `@key="Version"` express? Couldn't be this information presented as a part of `Entries` element (somthing like `<Entries version="..">`)?

Comment: I just want to make sure that one of the entry elements has name value of "Version". The version number is very important to have. I need to make sure it is specified somewhere in that list of entries. Is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: Sure there is:  specify a VersionEntry element, required to occur exactly once.  Or (as Jirka Š suggests) put the version number in an attribute on the parent.